# How to Repair Microsoft Surface v2 Enter Surface Mode

Tags: touch, pixelsense

We've received the new Microsoft Surface v2 this week, and I've done something such that it broken the Surface Mode.

**What should happen**

I could double-tap the shortcut to Enter Surface Mode, say ok to the dialogs that popped up, and it would take me to the SurfaceLoader (a program that just shows a ring of particles pulsing in an out of the center).  After a moment, the water-simulation Attract program would pop-up, where I could touch the center surface logo to see the list of registered Surface programs.

**What happens instead**

I double-tap the shortcut to Enter Surface Mode (turning on debugging), and nothing comes up past SurfaceLoader. It seems that the other programs are running, but SurfaceLoader is aggressively maintaining focus.

**What might have messed things up**

- Installed my Surface 1 Application
- Made my Surface 1 Application run on startup
- Installed Surface SDK Samples
- (Maybe) accidentally moved an important file elsewhere - (just because its so easy to accidentally moving things on the Surface in Windows 7 Touch.)

Let's go over each of these.

For my Surface 1 Application, built in XNA using the Surface 1 SDK, we used an .msi installer to install the program.  It ran, but being that Surface 1 is built around a small program called SurfaceInput.exe running in the background, the program did not respond to input.  The program was run at startup through a registry key.

- I have uninstalled the program through the control panel (double check this)
- I have double-checked the registry to make sure the keys are not still there

For the Surface SDK Samples, I got them from the Microsoft Surface 2 SDK at: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26716. After installing the SDK, I navigated (on the Surface) to C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Surface/v2.0/Samples/Surface Code Samples.zip.  I extracted the zipped files, and installed them with InstallSamples.bat.  Installation succeeded normally.

At some point, I was able to see a list of these in the Surface Application Launcher screen. I can no longer get to that point, so I'm unable to exactly recreate my steps.
I'm not sure where these examples extract to - the placement does not seem to be contained in InstallSamples.bat file, and I cannot find them with Windows Search.  Perhaps they are built in the same folder and merely registered elsewhere with the Surface, but since then I have done a series of System Backups.  When examining the Surface Configuration Editor, BingSurface is the only Application registered with it, leading me to believe these are probably not the cause.

Finally I may have accidentally moved some arbitrary file to some other directory.  This does sound rather horrible of me, and while I don't recall an instance where I've done this, it is incredibly easy to accidentally move a file or folder when Surface is in Windows 7 Touch mode.  Even while writing this, I somehow moved the taskbar from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen while it was locked with just two touches.  I don't think this is the problem, but its easy enough to do that I can't rule it out either.

To remedy this, I have tried Windows System Restore.  I was able to restore to a point after installing my Surface 1 app, but I have tried twice to Restore to the original state of the surface without success.  I waited 10-20 minutes for System Restore to show progress, and both times it stayed on the Initializing screen.  It was not graphically frozen, as the Windows loading circle was spinning, but from my previous experiences 20 minutes seemed to be way too long for this process to be going correctly.

**Things that do not work**

- **Running Enter Surface Mode w/ debugging** - eternal loading screen.  Can alt+tab to see Attract is running, but does not switch focus to Attract window.  Can hear the sounds of Attract play when I touch the surface on the loading window.
- **Running Surface Shell** - eternal loading screen.  Can hear the sounds of attract play.
- **Running Enter Surface Mode w/ debugging in Single Application Mode set to SurfaceBing** - eternal loading screen. Alt+tab reveals its running, but does not switch focus to bing window.
- **Running Surface Shell in Single Application Mode set to SurfaceBing** - eternal loading screen. Alt+tab reveals its running, but does not switch focus to bing window.
- **Running Surface Loader** - running it directly causes same problems as above.

**Things that do work**

- **Compiled Sample Project RawImageVisualizer on separate system** - runs great on the surface.  Can see what the pixelsense is seeing.
- **Launching Bing for Microsoft Windows Directly** - works just as it should
- **Launching Attract directly from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Surface\v2.0\Attract** - watery program comes up just as it should.
- **Environment Lighting Optimizer** - works totally fine.

It seems like something happened to SurfaceLoader, such that it thinks it should always be on top of everything.  I shall give System Restore another go, allowing it a full hour.  I will also double-check the properties of SurfaceLoader to make sure it doesn't have anything akin to "run on top" checked.

I know Surface 2 is new, but I would greatly appreciate any tips you have.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured it out by now, but for posterity's sake, I'm guessing you didn't have permissions set correctly.  You should always run the Surface Shell/Enter Surface Mode as Administrator or set the properties to always run as admin.  Your own programs always need high level permission.  If you don't run as admin, it seems to raise the alert window you get when Windows7 asks for higher level permissions but you never see it.  It just waits and waits.  "Surface Mode" is actually just a special user that's hidden until you enter it and never runs Windows Explorer or shows the desktop.  So you have to deal with Windows 7 permissions to have programs run for both users.  Hope that helps!